# Creating a ° in a xaml file

Tags: java, xaml, symbols, kaxaml

So, I'm making a xaml file using java. This is my line of code in java :

```
String newAnswer = e.getText().substring(0, 1) + "&#186;" + e.getText().substring(2);
```

Now

```
"&#186;"
```

This part should, according to Google, create a degrees symbol in my xaml file, however when I open the output file in xaml I get this: `&amp;#186;` , if i remove the `amp;` part it is correct, but I'd like Kaxaml to stop adding that in the first place, if anyone knows how to achieve this, that'd be greatly appreciated.

This is how my xaml gets saved

```
Utilities.saveXml(d, "Scherm1.xaml");
Utilities:
 public static void saveXml(Document document, String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer;
    XMLOutputter outputter;

    outputter = new XMLOutputter();
    outputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
    outputter.output(document, writer);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're creating the XAML.

Comment: How are you looking at the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
 + <TextBlock &#186;"/>
```